$L^2$-estimate of $\nabla R$ in $\partial_t R= \Delta R +R^2 -rR$
Consider 2-sphere $(S^2, g)$, and evolute its metric by
$$
\partial_t g_{ij} = (r-R) g_{ij}
$$
where $r$ is the average of $R$, and $R$ is scalar curvature. Then, there is
$$
\partial_t R= \Delta R + R^2 -rR   \tag{1}
$$
Now we know it converges to the metric of constant curvature from Chow's The Ricci flow on the 2-sphere (I didn't  read detail of Chow's paper).
On the other hand, we consider $\delta=\int_{S^2}(r-R)^2 d\mu$, where $\mu=\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}$ is area element. Then, the above convergence seemly imply $\frac{d}{dt}\delta\le 0$. By calculate, I have
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\delta= \int-2|\nabla R|^2 + (R-r)^2(R+r) d\mu
$$
This imply
$$
\int (R-r)^2(R+r) d\mu \le 2\int |\nabla R|^2 d\mu  \tag{2}
$$
Many years have passed, I am curious whether we have way to get (2) from (1) ?

In a few months, that's not a very good question.  Others choose to estimate useful quantities in order to prove a good result. But you just focus on the quantities, not how to get to that good result. 有点本末倒置了。
